# amazon aws ecr tag image without existing tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-registry

I'm trying to tag an older image in aws ecr.

While Amazon offer help on [retag](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/retag-aws-cli.html) images that HAS an existing tag. How do I tag an image with just imageDigest. Example, how do I tag the last image below with **"imageDigest": "sha256:9f61b77c31..."** to **"dev"**

```html
aws ecr list-images --repository-name my_aws_ecr_repo
{
    "imageIds": [
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:c115230398..."
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:236ce1ed44...",
            "imageTag": "latest"
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:c1dd997eb7..."
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:9f61b77c31..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`aws ecr batch-get-image` has an option to use imageDigest instead of imageTag for image-ids: `--image-ids imageDigest=`

For example:

```
MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-ids imageDigest="sha256:xxx" --query "images[].imageManifest" --output text)
```